# Property 'propertyTrue' does not exist on type 'a | b'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a type that depends on a specific property, but I get the error "Property 'propertyTrue' does not exist on type 'a | b'"

```
interface a {
  propertyTrue: true
}

interface b {
  propertyNumber: number,
}

interface c {
  [key: string]: a | b
}

const obj: c = {
  key1: {
    propertyTrue: true,
  },
  key2: {
    propertyNumber: 123,
  },
}

for (const key in obj) {
  if (obj[key].propertyTrue) console.log(obj[key].propertyTrue)
}
```

Please tell me why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to narrow the type. There are several ways of doing this. One of them is [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```
interface a {
  discriminator: "a",
  propertyTrue: true,
}

interface b {
  discriminator: "b",
  propertyNumber: number,
}
```

Then:

```
const item = obj[key]; // item is 'a | b' here
if (item.discriminator === "a") {
    console.log(obj[key].propertyTrue); // item is 'a' here
}
```

---

Another way is using type guards:

```
const isA = (obj: a | b): obj is a => {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("properyTrue");
};
```

Then:

```
const item = obj[key]; // item is 'a | b' here
if (isA(item)) {
    console.log(item.propertyTrue); // item is 'a' here
}
```

Comment: In the second approach, I get the same error in the line return obj.propertyTrue != null

Comment: @Dmitriybo you are right, try the edited version

Answer (score 0):

The problem is interface 'b' does not have that variable option.

**You can cast your method like this to make it work:**

```
if ((obj[key] as a).propertyTrue)
```